# Code Not Shown in VS code while debugging asp.net docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

I am learning docker with asp.net core. Create a mvc application, dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file. I have docker file as below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as debug

#install debugger for NET Core
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

RUN mkdir /app/
WORKDIR /app/

COPY ./src/testapp.csproj /app/testapp.csproj
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./src/ /app/
RUN mkdir /out/
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore --output /out/ --configuration Release
EXPOSE 80
CMD dotnet run --urls "http://0.0.0.0:80"
```

Also, I have docker compose file as below:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: sachin

  pg_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
    volumes:
      - pg_admin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: sachin.maharjan@dishhome.com.np
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password

  web:
    container_name: csharp
    build:
      context: .
      target: debug
    ports:
     - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/
    depends_on:
     - db

volumes:
  postgres:
  pg_admin:
```

I have installed docker extension and C# extension in my vs code. I have lunch.js file inside .vscode folder.

The content of lunch.js:

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Docker Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": [ "exec", "-i", "csharp" ],
                "debuggerPath": "/root/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/work": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
            }
        },
       
    ]
}
```

The debugger stop at break point but it shows error like this.

[image]

Is this error with volume mapping or did I set up lunch.json wrong?

Comment: WIll it show the file name which it cannot find if you click `Create File` link?

Comment: Its HomeController's Index method where i put break point.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in lunch.json in the source map section, I mapped the wrong folder in local file system with file system with docker.
Previously, MapSetting section was like below:

```
   "sourceFileMap": 
   {
     "/work": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
   }
```

Then I change folder mapping with right one and erorr is solved.

```
"sourceFileMap": {
            "/src": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
        }
```